# Waiting for asynchronous callback in Android's IntentService

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, intentservice

I have an `IntentService` that starts an asynchronous task in another class and should then be waiting for the result.

The problem is that the `IntentService` will finish as soon as the `onHandleIntent(...)` method has finished running, right?

That means, normally, the `IntentService` will immediately shut down after starting the asynchronous task and will not be there anymore to receive the results.

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService implements MyCallback {

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        MyOtherClass.runAsynchronousTask(this);
    }

}

public interface MyCallback {

    public void onReceiveResults(Object object);

}

public class MyOtherClass {

    public void runAsynchronousTask(MyCallback callback) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                // do some long-running work
                callback.onReceiveResults(...);
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

How can I make the snippet above work? I've already tried putting `Thread.sleep(15000)` (arbitrary duration) in `onHandleIntent(...)` after starting the task. Itseems to work.

But it definitely doesn't seem to be clean solution. Maybe there are even some serious problems with that.

Any better solution?

Comment: What is stopping you from making a synchronous version of the same thing?

Comment: you can use bindservice for it . http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html this will help me a lot .

Comment: @ianhanniballake: `MyOtherClass` is actually part of a third-party component that I rather don't like to change. The method in that class always delivers its results via callbacks, not synchronously.

Comment: @mcd: Bound services are only for the use case where the `Service` reports back to another application component, usually an `Activity`, aren't they?

Comment: yup but you can user service class instead sorry for not read your question properly

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I keep the Thread of an IntentService alive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700288/how-do-i-keep-the-thread-of-an-intentservice-alive)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the standard `Service` class instead of `IntentService`, start your asynchronous task from the `onStartCommand()` callback, and destroy the `Service` when you receive the completion callback.

The issue with that would be to correctly handle the destruction of the `Service` in the case of concurrently running tasks as a result of the `Service` being started again while it was already running. If you need to handle this case, then you might need to set up a running counter or a set of callbacks, and destroy the `Service` only when they are all completed.

Comment: Agreed. `IntentService` is not designed for this scenario.

Comment: @CommonsWare why does the [google sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java) for GCM set up an http call in an IntentService (sendRegistrationToServer method). Surely 99.9% of people will want to wait for the response from their server when sending the gcm token right? Yet waiting for a callback from an http call inside an IntentService is not what IntentService is designed for.

Comment: @AdamJohns: "Yet waiting for a callback from an http call inside an IntentService is not what IntentService is designed for" -- I don't know what you mean by "callback" in this case. Doing HTTP I/O is a perfectly reasonable thing for an `IntentService` to do, so long as it does so synchronously. If you have additional concerns in this area, I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @CommonsWare when I say callback I mean I want to send an http request to my server with the gcm token and the "callback" would be getting the response back from the server. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36501842/1438339

Answer (score 14):

I agree with corsair992 that typically you should not have to make asynchronous calls from an IntentService because IntentService already does its work on a worker thread. However, if you *must* do so you can use [CountDownLatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService implements MyCallback {
    private CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public MyIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        MyOtherClass.runAsynchronousTask(this);
        doneSignal.await();
    }

}

@Override
public void onReceiveResults(Object object) {
    doneSignal.countDown();
}

public interface MyCallback {

    public void onReceiveResults(Object object);

}

public class MyOtherClass {

    public void runAsynchronousTask(MyCallback callback) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                // do some long-running work
                callback.onReceiveResults(...);
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are there any downsides to this? Still seems like a pretty straight forward option?

Comment: To make it more production quality you'd probably want to use something other than a new Thread, perhaps an Executor but the basic idea of using a CountDownLatch is pretty basic.

Answer (score 6):

If you are still looking for ways to use Intent Service for asynchronous callback, you can have a wait and notify on thread as follows,

```
private Object object = new Object();

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Make API which return async calback.

    // Acquire wait so that the intent service thread will wait for some one to release lock.
    synchronized (object) {
        try {
            object.wait(30000); // If you want a timed wait or else you can just use object.wait()
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("Message", "Interrupted Exception while getting lock" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

// Let say this is the callback being invoked
private class Callback {
    public void complete() {
        // Do whatever operation you want

        // Releases the lock so that intent service thread is unblocked.
        synchronized (object) {
            object.notifyAll();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: can u plz examplin more this

Answer (score 3):

My favorite option is to expose two similar methods, for example:

```
public List<Dog> getDogsSync();
public void getDogsAsync(DogCallback dogCallback);
```

Then the implementation could be as follows:

```
public List<Dog> getDogsSync() {
    return database.getDogs();
}

public void getDogsAsync(DogCallback dogCallback) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Dog>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Dog> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return getDogsSync();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Dog> dogs) {
            dogCallback.success(dogs);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Then in your `IntentService` you can call `getDogsSync()` because it's already on a background thread.

Comment: Thanks, that's precisely what I did as well to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doomed without changing `MyOtherClass`.

With changing that class you have two options:

1. Make an synchronous call. `IntentService` is already spawning a background `Thread` for you.
2. Return the newly created `Thread` in `runAsynchronousTask()` and call `join()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it probably makes more sense to use `Service` directly rather than `IntentService`, but if you are using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), you can implement an `AbstractFuture` as your callback handler, which lets you conveniently ignore the details of synchronization:

```
public class CallbackFuture extends AbstractFuture<Object> implements MyCallback {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveResults(Object object) {
        set(object);
    }

    // AbstractFuture also defines `setException` which you can use in your error 
    // handler if your callback interface supports it
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        setException(e);
    }
}
```

`AbstractFuture` defines `get()` which blocks until the `set()` or `setException()` methods are called, and returns a value or raises an exception, respectively.

Then your `onHandleIntent` becomes:

```
    @Override
    protected final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        CallbackFuture future = new CallbackFuture();
        MyOtherClass.runAsynchronousTask(future);
        try {
            Object result = future.get();
            // handle result
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
```