# Android GCM Sending token to server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-service, intentservice

The [GCM Sample Project](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/RegistrationIntentService.java) gives a stubbed out example of sending a GCM token to your server:

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            ...
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

            // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

but this is done in an `IntentService` which finishes as soon as `onHandleIntent` returns right? So if starting an http call to send the token with the popular [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library, I'm not even seeing my `onStart` hit:

```
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    post("/devices", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        // TODO: MAKE SURE ONSTART ACTUALLY CALLED TO MAKE SURE REQUEST AT LEAST GOES UPSTREAM EVEN IF I DON'T RECEIVE A CALLBACK SINCE IN INTENTSERVICE
        // IF NOT THEN MIGHT HAVE TO CHANGE THE INTENTSERVICE TO A SERVICE FOR DEVICE REGISTRATION
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // not actually using callback because request sent from intentservice
            Log.d("tagzzz", "sending upstream");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            // not actually using callback because request sent from intentservice
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            // not actually using callback because request sent from intentservice
        }
    });
}
```

Will my http request even be sent upstream before `onHandleIntent` returns and finishes the `IntentService`? If not, why does Google give this as their example for sending your token to your server?

Comment: IntentService has a dedicated background thread on which it runs. So you no need to start http call on other thread instead use current background thread. If you actually want to use dedicated thread for calling web-service then you can prevent Intent Service onHandleIntent from getting executed by using CountdownLatch. But it is not good approach. Please share your inputs?

Comment: @SagarTrehan sorry I'm not understanding what you mean when you say "you no need to start http call on other thread instead user current background thread.". I'm starting the http call on the current thread, but the async callback that is passed to the http library call is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will my http request even be sent upstream before onHandleIntent returns and finishes the IntentService?

Given that you are using a library named "android-async-http", I would assume that the default behavior is for it to execute the HTTP asynchronously. It is indeterminate whether or not the `post()` call will complete its work before `onHandleIntent()` returns, but it seems unlikely.

> why does Google give this as their example for sending your token to your server?

Google doesn't. Google has a stub `sendRegistrationToServer()`, as you can see in your first code listing. I am not aware of any Google examples that use the "android-async-http" library.

**You** decided to use an asynchronous mechanism for sending that HTTP request. That is an inappropriate choice for inside an `IntentService`. Now, perhaps that library has a synchronous option, in which case you could switch to that. Otherwise, use something else synchronous for the HTTP request (`HttpURLConnection`, OkHttp3, etc.) from the `IntentService`.

Note that Volley is not a great choice here, insofar as Volley is also strongly tilted towards asynchronous work.

Comment: Ah ok so if I use a synchronous http call, the `IntentService` will stay alive until I get a response from the server?

Comment: @AdamJohns: Yes. Assuming that your HTTP operation should be fairly short (e.g., a second or two), that's all you need. For extensive work, you may need to start thinking about `WakeLock` and stuff.

Comment: Just an additional comment to the final note of this answer: I have plenty of apps nowadays that use `IntentService`s making synchronous HTTP requests using Volley without any problem. The `RequestFuture.newFuture()` mechanism it provides is quite clean and straightforward.